# Facebook Like Button for htm

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I have been on many sites looking for answers and this is my first attempt at getting an answer. I wrote the code for my web site and only know enough to be dangerous.

I am attempting to add a Facebook like button to the pages. It's written in HTML and everything else is XML or open, none that I have any experience with.
So here is an example:
 http://www.2snapsup.com/pages/mugshots12/ms291201/tsu08-120120-214314-0029.htm

When I try to "like it" I get the page counter displayed.

I have another attempt on this page: http://www.2snapsup.com/index.htm

As you can see if you look at the code, I have tried different variations with mixed results. I thought I would ask for help before I rebuild the pages.

I am normally a self-sufficient person but I am pretty frustrated.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation facebook made for you : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You'll find all answers you are looking for